# Using Regular expression to replace repetitive punctuation?

Tags: regex, punctuation

Here is a sentence like this:

```
Happy birthday!! I have a good day. :)
```

I want to know how to process these sentence using regular expression to the following formate:

```
Happy birthday! I have a good day.
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the emoticon too?

Comment: yes, the emoticon need to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in PERL (since you didn't specify a programming language.

```
my $str = "Happy birthday!! I have a good day. :)";
$str =~ s/([.!?]){2,}/$1/g;    #remove multiple punctuation
$str =~ s/[:;()]+//g;          #remove emoticon
print $str;
```